# float _Complex identifier variant for Windows?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

```
# define COMPLEX_FLOAT float _Complex 
# define _Complex_I 1.0fi
```

This is present in the main header file of my project.

```
extern COMPLEX_FLOAT quantum_conj(COMPLEX_FLOAT a);
```

This, in another header file. However, I get `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'quantum_conj'` when I compile using MSVC. I have included `<math.h>`.

I guess there's no identifier as `float _Complex` in windows. This project compiles fine for UNIX/LINUX families. Also, I came to know that these macros(`_Complex_I and _Complex`) are present in `<complex.h>` for gnu/bsd distros. However, there is no `complex.h` header file for windows.

But, I want to compile this for Windows. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Complex arithmetic is a C99 feature. And MSVC only supports something approximating C89. MS has publicly stated that it won't go beyond C89 for its C compiler.

Ergo, you need a different compiler. The GNU compiler, for example, will do the job. On Windows that usually means the mingw port.